# Buying all the timeshares

Tags: real-estate

What if you own a fractional property or a timeshare which we all know are a rip off, but then you bought everyone else’s time shares for that particular fractional property. Would you own that property out right?

Comment: Timeshares do not imply ownership.

Comment: The details might vary depending on the exact language of the timeshare contract. "Timeshare" is not a legal construct with a fixed definition. It is a convention to describe a whole class of contracts.

Comment: It's a convention to describe a common scam :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Timeshares are a [leasehold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leasehold_estate) - they give no right to the [freehold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freehold_(law))

A timeshare is a type of leasehold tenancy- if it were legal to acquire more than one on the same property (which is usually prohibited beyond a certain point) then all that would do is increase the period you were allowed to stay. The freehold in the property remains with the landlord.

Comment: So in theory, if the timeshare was a property freeheld by say 50 people with (2 weeks for maintenance) my theory would work where if you bought out the other 49 people you would then own the property. From what you are telling me that is a rare instance because the holding company has already thought of my theory and put in legal protections to protect their scam.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch In that case you would have a leasehold for 100% of the time, but the condo still stays the property of the timeshare company. The company would retain all rights which are not specifically transfered as part of the timeshare contract.

Comment: Timeshare companies are delighted for people with one week to buy more weeks. It is incorrect and illogical that the timeshare company disallows a person from owning more than chunk of time.

Comment: My theory was if you owned all the shares you would own the property (which from my research might be true in some cases), but if it was a freehold time share you probably could pull this off.